# Is there a way to make "Relative Path" the default for adding JAR files in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, relative-path, absolute-path

In netbeans, if you right click on a project, go to `Properties` then click on `Libraries`, it shows you a list of current JAR files added to your project.  Then you can add more libraries by clicking `Add JAR/Folder`.  However, when you click on a JAR file, it defaults to `Absolute Path`.  In my particular case, this is **never** what I want and I often just hit `Open` and add the file incorrectly.  When I check my project changes into SVN, the absolute path breaks the build for all of my team members.

So, is there a way to make `Relative Path` the default?

UPDATE:
To clarify, I have multiple projects open in netbeans.

Main - /lib/ contains all of my JAR files.  Main refers to some of the JAR files in the lib folder, adding JAR files as described uses `Relative Path` by default.

PluginA - Uses and refers to some of the JAR files inside Main/lib.  I'm adding the JAR files as described and they are defaulting to `Absolute Path`.  I'd like **these** to use `Relative Path` by default.

Comment: I used to create a `lib` folder *inside* the project folder (as those jars were also added to SVN) and Netbeans goes with `Relative Path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I suspect the existence of [this bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169967) means the answer is that there is no way to make **Relative Path** the default.

Looking for alternatives: in the same bug there is [this description of NB behaviour](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169967#c4):

> 1. If the JAR is considered "collocated" with the project basedir according to some provider of this information (generally a version
>      control system which checks whether file paths are in the same
>      checkout), then Relative is checked by default. (Since it can be
>      assured that someone else checking out the same sources would indeed
>      be able to use the same path.)
> 2. If the JAR can be referred to using a named variable, that is used.

So, if the projects live in the same SVN repository, using a single woking copy (which I did until recently and why I never noticed the **Absolute** / **Relative** problem) could work.

Otherwise maybe defining a variable for that `/lib` directory could be a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just getting to take a look at this again.  A variable would work only if I could make it a relative path, and I can't.  Otherwise all of my developers have to create the variable on their machine too.  The projects are all in 1 folder under source control, but I'm not checking them out using netbeans, so that isn't working either.

Comment: You got it - if I use Netbeans to check it out of my repository it DOES choose Relative Path as the default.  The downside is, I can't figure out a way to do it if I just have a bunch of folders sitting next to each other on my disk.